# How can SwiftUI remember Auth0 user when he closes the app?

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, swiftui, auth0

I'm creating a SwiftUI App, with Auth0 authentication.
I can log in to my application, then i access all the stuff.
But if im logged in and I close my app (quit + close of background app)I lost my connection

If I restart my app I'm disconnected.
I'm searching how to "remember" the user, so he does not have to log every launch.

If its not clear dont hesitate to ask me.

Comment: You likely need to store something securely on-device... either in the Keychain if it's sensitive or CoreData or SwiftData if it's not. You could also use UserDefaults. Good article: https://medium.com/@rashadsh/data-persistance-in-swift-different-ways-to-save-your-data-954cd2559a75 and https://medium.com/@ranga.c222/how-to-save-sensitive-data-in-keychain-in-ios-using-swift-c839d0e98f9d

Comment: I think i'm gonna use UserDefaults.
In my code there is a bool : isAuthenticated.
If true 
MainView()
else
AuthView()

Do you think I can store the value of this bool in UserDefaults ?

Comment: If you use Auth0 then you should save the Credentials after the login and you can retrieve it to check the user's state:
Check this:
https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0-swift/auth0-swift-save-and-renew-tokens

Comment: @Zoli I'll check that. Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: @Tom yes - if you are using SwiftUI you can use [`@AppStorage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/appstorage), which is like `@State` but stored in the `UserDefaults`.